# Kafka + helm + kubernetes integration. Dynamic broker url

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, service-discovery

**What I have**

I have helm chart which represents my application.
I also have separate chart which deploys kafka with few pods, clusterIP service as well as headless service.
Definition looks like this

```
"$(MY_POD_NAME).{{ $fullname }}-headless.{{ $releaseNamespace }}.svc.{{ $clusterDomain }}:{{ $interBrokerPort }}
```

End result broker url

```
my-kafka-pod-0.release-kafka-chart-name-headless.release.svc.cluster.local:9092,my-kafka-pod-1.release-kafka-chart-name-headless.release.svc.cluster.local:9092,my-kafka-pod-2.release-kafka-chart-name-headless.release.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

**UC**

Now let's assume that I have an environment where I already have deployed kafka chart, and now I am going to deploy the application chart, however I need somehow to pass the correct endpoint (brokerurl).

I don't want to put hardcoded values (IMO, if it is in values.yaml it is still hardcoded), because I don't know possible release name of kafka chart, I don't know how many pods will be deployed, hence I can't know how my url will look like.

I know that I can override the endpoint when I am deploying the app chart. But I would like to have some generic reference to running kafka.

Is there any ability how I could do that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvpq4jqtuZ8 maybe this can help me ?

Comment: You can provide a `helm install --set kafkaUrl=...` option, or put the setting in a per-deployment file and `helm install -f qa-env.yaml` to specify it at deployment time.